# How to change a theme depending on user's login preference

Tags: php, mysql, database

Being a student, I'm fairly new to this, so please bear with me.

Is it possible for a website to change it's "theme" (such as site nav colour, background, colour, etc) based on a user's login preferences?

The name of the theme will be saved in a members table on a MySQL database under "preference".

I'm creating the site using PHP.

Thanks

Comment: You'll want to look at creating multiple css files and then outputting the chosen theme name as the css filename in the PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to create multiple css files, like MCMXCII said in the comments, and then save the css file name in the database.
That way you can echo that to the stylesheet "import" like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <link href="<?php echo $filename;// From database ?>" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to save the user's preferred theme in the db against their account, for example:

```
user_id | theme
---------------
    1   |  red
```

Then create multiple css files, which can be loaded, with a default, based on the user's selected theme, something like the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $user->theme ? $user->theme . '.css': 'default.css' ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Dynamic CSS.
Please refer the below code :

```
<html><head>
....
<style ... src="..." />
<style>
// from db
#custom { background: #<?php echo $colour; ?> }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you make multiple sylesheets for the different themes forexample
dark-theme.css (with the styles specific to the dark theme)
light-theme.css etc (with the styles specific to the light theme)

Then store the use preferred theme name in a session when the user logs in such that you can load the files like this in your page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="projectFolder/cssFolder/<?php echo $theme_name.'.css'; ?>"/>
```

---

The above code should allow you have the different style sheets loaded into the page